# How to select records with multiple ids from the MYSQL database

Tags: python, mysql

I am using python and MYSQL for fetching data , i know this is a basic question, but i am unable to find it.

I had a list of ids generated from some dictionary in python like example

```
dic = {'1': u'', '3': u'', '2': u'', '4': u''}
lis_ids = dic.keys()

query = "SELECT * FROM File_upload where id IN %s" % [int(i) for i in a]

print query
```

**Result**

```
"SELECT * FROM File_upload where id IN [1, 3, 2, 4]"
```

The above result will display syntax error because actually it should be as below

```
"SELECT * FROM File_upload where id IN (1, 3, 2, 4)"
```

How we can convert the list in to tuple in python, because i am getting the ids from a list.

**Edited Code**

Actually this is the second scenario which i got

The dict i have is

```
dic = {'submit': u'', '1': u'', '3': u'', '2': u'', '4': u'', 'groups': {}}
lis_ids = dic.keys()
```

Actually we will get `submit` and `groups` also in to the list, but i want only integer keys as ids

so also i want to implement this functionality like `if not len(key) > 1 take the key`

So can anyone able to implement all this functionality in one line as below ?

Comment: Nice question and very helpful.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
dic = {'submit': u'', '1': u'', '3': u'', '2': u'', '4': u'', 'groups': {}}
list_ids = [elem for elem in dic.keys() if elem.isdigit()]

query = "SELECT * FROM File_upload where id IN (%s)" % ','.join(list_ids)

print query
```

Comment: Updated with the second scenario.

Comment: This works for some cases, but what if there are meta-characters in the list_ids?

Comment: eg `'123;'.isdigit()` returns false, then not enter the list, Is that what you refer to @JayElston?

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
query = "SELECT * FROM File_upload where id IN %s" % str(tuple(int(i) for i in a))
```

(The `str()` call is required, unfortunately; you'll get a TypeError without it.)

---

If you want to just take the keys that are convertible to integers, try this:

```
def only_numbers(seq):
    for i in seq:
        try:
            yield int(i)
        except ValueError:
            pass

query = "SELECT * FROM File_upload where id IN %s" % str(tuple(only_numbers(dic.keys())))
```

It's not as simple, because you have to try to convert each key to an integer and handle errors by doing nothing, so we need a generator function to handle that part of it.

Comment: wow thank you very much also i edited the code please have a look at it